Convert json containing nested list using json_normalize function and create dataframe
{
"Serialnumber": 1,
"JSON": {
"body": {
"ver": "1",
"dt": 169,
"od": "OBJECT_ID",
"bin": "Vbin",
"myname": "VME",
"msgss": [
{
"code": "TLHGH1",
"Details": {
"no": 1,
"rep": 4
},
"pngds": [
{
"id": "ID1",
"mpo": 16,
"mkg": "up"
}
]
},
{
"code": "TLHGH2",
"Details": {
"no": 2,
"rep": 5
},
"pngds": [
{
"id": "ID2",
"mpo": 17,
"mkg": "down"
}
]
}
]
}
}
}
I need to parse above json and get the output details like below.


Please don't share pictures of data, copy-paste it here and format it accordingly. Also, please share your attempt to solve the problem.

@MilosStojanovic this is dummy data anyway

Yes, but it's easier for someone who wants to help you to have everything he needs provided in good format.

You can use pandas.json_normalize:
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=["msgss", "pngds"],
    meta=[
        "ver",
        "Datetime",
        "od",
        "bin",
        "myname",
        ["msgss", "code"],
        ["msgss", "Details", "no"],
        ["msgss", "Details", "rep"],
    ],
)

df.columns = [
    "id",
    "mpo",
    "mkg",
    "ver",
    "Datetime",
    "od",
    "bin",
    "myName",
    "code",
    "no",
    "rep",
]

   id  mpo mkg ver       Datetime         od   bin myName   code no rep
0  ID   16  up   1  1699439129329  OBJECT_ID  Vbin    VME  TLHGH  1   4
1  ID   16  up   2  1699439129329  OBJECT_ID  Vbin    VME  TLHGH  1   4


For your updated json, you can just add "JSON", "body" in front of record_path and every field in meta, as I mentioned in the comments:

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=["JSON", "body", "msgss", "pngds"],
    meta=[
        ["JSON", "body", "ver"],
        ["JSON", "body", "dt"],
        ["JSON", "body", "od"],
        ["JSON", "body", "bin"],
        ["JSON", "body", "myname"],
        ["JSON", "body", "msgss", "code"],
        ["JSON", "body", "msgss", "Details", "no"],
        ["JSON", "body", "msgss", "Details", "rep"],
    ],
)

    id  mpo   mkg JSON.body.ver JSON.body.dt  ... JSON.body.bin JSON.body.myname JSON.body.msgss.code JSON.body.msgss.Details.no JSON.body.msgss.Details.rep
0  ID1   16    up             1          169  ...          Vbin              VME               TLHGH1                          1                           4
1  ID2   17  down             1          169  ...          Vbin              VME               TLHGH2                          2                           5


{ "Serialnumber": 1, "JSON": { "body": { "ver": "1", "dt": 169, "od": "OBJECT_ID", "bin": "Vbin", "myname": "VME", "msgss": [ { "code": "TLHGH1", "Details": { "no": 1, "rep": 4 }, "pngds": [ { "id": "ID", "mpo": 16, "mkg": "up" } ] }, { "code": "TLHGH2", "Details": { "no": 1, "rep": 4 }, "pngds": [ { "id": "ID", "mpo": 16, "mkg": "up" } ] } ] } } }

Hi, i have slight change in json format like above where i have change record_path=["json","body"] due to multiple levels but its not working, can you please let me know the correct query

@Shankar With this new example, you'd need to add "JSON", "body" in front of record_path and every field in meta. Read the documentation to learn more: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

unfortunately i am getting error after adding  df = pd.json_normalize(
data,"JSON", "body",
record_path=["msgss", "pngds"]---------error:TypeError: _json_normalize() got multiple values for argument 'record_path'

@Shankar I updated the answer. If you have new inquiries, please read the documentation thoroughly and create new questions. Hope this helps.

Use nested list comprehension for flatten values to list of dictionaries and call DataFrame constructor:
L = [ { "ver": "1", "Datetime": 1699439129329, "od": "OBJECT_ID", "bin": "Vbin", "myname": "VME", "msgss": [ { "code": "TLHGH", "Details": { "no": 1, "rep": 4 }, "pngds": [ { "id": "ID", "mpo": 16, "mkg": "up", } ] } ] }, { "ver": "2", "Datetime": 1699439129329, "od": "OBJECT_ID", "bin": "Vbin", "myname": "VME", "msgss": [ { "code": "TLHGH", "Details": { "no": 1, "rep": 4 }, "pngds": [ { "id": "ID", "mpo": 16, "mkg": "up", } ] } ] } ]


df = pd.DataFrame([{**x, **{'code': y['code']} ,**y.pop('Details'), **z} 
                   for x in L 
                   for y in x.pop('msgss') 
                   for z in y.pop('pngds')])
print (df)
  ver       Datetime         od   bin myname   code  no  rep  id  mpo mkg
0   1  1699439129329  OBJECT_ID  Vbin    VME  TLHGH   1    4  ID   16  up
1   2  1699439129329  OBJECT_ID  Vbin    VME  TLHGH   1    4  ID   16  up

